# Gmail does not recognize an email address for no apparent reason

Tags: gmail, google-apps-email

When I attempt to address my email message by selecting a group and hit SEND I get the error message:

> The address "seeminglygoodemail@example.com" in the "Bcc" field was not recognized. Please make sure that all addresses are properly formed.

If I select this particular email by itself it works.  I've verified that the email is well formed.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the email address had a bad character that is not visible. Perhaps a Unicode 2-byte character that Gmail is displaying properly but storing as two bytes and tripping up its own parser.

The solution is to simply re-enter manually the email address.

Comment: I had to delete the `to:` field and re-manually type the email address then it sent. Thank you!